# copy field with replacement from one database to another

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

How to copy all rows in one field with full replacement?

anna2 - database
exp_weblog_data - table
field_id_2 - fields

to

anna1 - database
exp_channel_data - table
field_id_2 - fields

exp_weblog_data and exp_channel_data have the same relationship between fields entry_id and field_id_2.

before:

```
exp_channel_data (from anna1)   exp_weblog_data (from database anna2)
entry_id   field_id_2           entry_id   field_id_2
988        blabla               988        doomdoom
989        kryakrya             989        roomroom
...                             ...
```

after:

```
exp_channel_data                exp_weblog_data
entry_id   field_id_2           entry_id   field_id_2
988        doomdoom             988        doomdoom
989        roomroom             989        roomroom
...                             ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming database server is mysql and both databases (anna2 and anna1) is on it AND you have proper credentials to connect to both, you can do a cross db update/select.

It looks like you're trying an update, not a creation of new records rom

```
 UPDATE anna1.exp_channel_data a1, anna2.exp_weblog_data a2 
      SET a1.field_id_2 = a2.field_id_2    
      WHERE a1.id = a2.id;
```

The cross DB insert would be similarly done.